# adding new row to DataGridView with duplicated check data issue

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, duplicates

my code works fine if i removed while loop, but when i use this block to look at duplicated items it adds one item and works fine on duplicated filter but i could't add any more items to the DataGridView
i'm sure the issue inside while loop code but i could't find it.

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductBarcode ='" + ProductBarcode.Text + "' ", Con)
Dim dt2 As New DataTable
Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
adp.Fill(dt2)
If dt2.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    While i < dgv_SaleProduct.Rows.Count
        If dgv_SaleProduct.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString = ProductBarcode.Text.ToString Then
            If MessageBox.Show("هذا المنتج موجود مسبقاً في الفاتورة هل تريد تحديث الكمية لنفس المنتج و إضافتها للفاتورة؟", "تنبيه", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) = DialogResult.No Then
                Exit Sub
            Else
                dgv_SaleProduct.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value = dgv_SaleProduct.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value + Val(Quantity.Text)
                dgv_SaleProduct.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value = dgv_SaleProduct.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value * dgv_SaleProduct.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value
                InvoiceTotal()
                ProductBarcode.Text = ""
                Quantity.Text = ""
                ProductBarcode.Focus()
                NumberItems.Text = dgv_SaleProduct.RowCount
            End If
            Return
        End If
    End While
    dgv_SaleProduct.Rows.Add()
    x = dgv_SaleProduct.Rows.Count - 1
    dgv_SaleProduct(0, x).Value = dt2.Rows(0).Item("ProductID")
    dgv_SaleProduct(1, x).Value = dt2.Rows(0).Item("ProductBarcode")
    dgv_SaleProduct(2, x).Value = dt2.Rows(0).Item("ProductName")
    dgv_SaleProduct(3, x).Value = dt2.Rows(0).Item("SellingPrice")
    dgv_SaleProduct(4, x).Value = Quantity.Text
    dgv_SaleProduct(5, x).Value = Val(dt2.Rows(0).Item("SellingPrice")) * Val(Quantity.Text)
End If
InvoiceTotal()
ProductBarcode.Text = ""
Quantity.Text = ""
ProductBarcode.Focus()
NumberItems.Text = dgv_SaleProduct.RowCount
```

Comment: Use the debugger and then you can find the issue for yourself. If you don't know how to debug, now is the time to learn. Set a breakpoint, step through the code and examine the state at each step. As soon as the state differs from your expectation, you've found the issue. Even if you can't solve it, at least you can give us far more relevant information. No question should ever be asked here without debugging first.

Comment: It appears you are trying to “add” two values and another place trying to “multiply" two values. Example; the line… `dgv_SaleProduct.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value = dgv_SaleProduct.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value + Val(Quantity.Text)` will fail since the property `Value` for the CELL is a “generic” `Object` and regardless of what is returned from `Val(Quantity.Text)`, the compiler is not going to know how to “ADD” something to a “generic” `Object type. A cast of some numeric type is missing.

Comment: Lastly, it is hard to understand what you are asking. It is clear, the above errors are certainly going to cause problems until you possibly “cast” the `Object` to some numeric value. I recommend you go into greater detail as to what you are trying to achieve overall. The title about “duplicated check data?” is confusing and the explanation and code only lead to more confusion.